# Two problems in commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a local ring and $L$ and $F$ be free $A$-modules of finite rank. Consider bases $e_1,\dots,e_m$ and $f_1,\dots,f_n$ of $L$ and $F$. To a homomorphism $u:L\rightarrow F$ associate the matrix $M=(a_{ij})$, with $u(e_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}f_i$. Show that:

> 1) the ideal generated by the $n$-minors of $M$ and the annihilator of coker $u$  have the same radical;
>   2) coker $u$ is free of rank $n-l$ iff $M$ has an invertible $l$-minor.

When $u$ is surjective, 1) is easy. I have no idea about the situation $u$ is not surjective. For 2) I also have no idea. How do you think about it?

Comment: Read the section 1.4 from Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*.